# Performance issues with UPDATE in AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

I have a small performance issue with one of my database triggers in my MS-SQL Server 2014 database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_T_TPM_Vehicle_Update] ON [dbo].[T_TPM_Vehicle]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE T_TPM_Vehicle SET LastUpdated = getdate() 
       WHERE Vehicle_Number IN (SELECT Vehicle_Number FROM inserted)

UPDATE T_TPM_Vehicle SET [DisturbedSince] = getdate() 
       WHERE Vehicle_Number IN (SELECT Vehicle_Number FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Emergency_Stop = 1)
         AND Vehicle_Number IN (SELECT Vehicle_Number FROM deleted WHERE deleted.Emergency_Stop = 0)

INSERT INTO T_TPM_Vehicle_HistoricalData
       ([Vehicle_Ref]
       ,[Vehicle_Number]
       ,[Vehicle_Type]
       ,[Pos_X]
       ,[Pos_Y]
       ,[Alpha]
       ,[LastAutoPos_X]
       ,[LastAutoPos_Y]
       ,[LastAutoAlpha]
       ,[Automatic]
       ,[Manual]
       ,[Blocked]
       ,[Loaded]
       ,[Stoped]
       ,[Emergency_Stop]
       ,[User_Required]
       ,[BatteryAlmostEmpty]
       ,[BatteryEmpty]
       ,[BatteryLevel]
       ,[ChargingRelaisEnable]
       ,[NavOK]
       ,[PowerOn]
       ,[Available]
       ,[OperatingMinutes]
       ,[UpdateOperatingMinutes]
       ,[DataChangedByVIS]
       ,[Blockingsreleased]
       ,[Cancelled]
       ,[ProductID]
       ,[HUIdent1]
       ,[HUIdent2]
       ,[HUType]
       ,[DisturbedSince])
 SELECT inserted.[Vehicle_Ref]
  ,inserted.[Vehicle_Number]
  ,inserted.[Vehicle_Type]
  ,inserted.[Pos_X]
  ,inserted.[Pos_Y]
  ,inserted.[Alpha]
  ,inserted.[LastAutoPos_X]
  ,inserted.[LastAutoPos_Y]
  ,inserted.[LastAutoAlpha]
  ,inserted.[Automatic]
  ,inserted.[Manual]
  ,inserted.[Blocked]
  ,inserted.[Loaded]
  ,inserted.[Stoped]
  ,inserted.[Emergency_Stop]
  ,inserted.[User_Required]
  ,inserted.[BatteryAlmostEmpty]
  ,inserted.[BatteryEmpty]
  ,inserted.[BatteryLevel]
  ,inserted.[ChargingRelaisEnable]
  ,inserted.[NavOK]
  ,inserted.[PowerOn]
  ,inserted.[Available]
  ,inserted.[OperatingMinutes]
  ,inserted.[UpdateOperatingMinutes]
  ,inserted.[DataChangedByVIS]
  ,inserted.[Blockingsreleased]
  ,inserted.[Cancelled]
  ,inserted.[ProductID]
  ,inserted.[HUIdent1]
  ,inserted.[HUIdent2]
  ,inserted.[HUType]
  ,inserted.[DisturbedSince] 
FROM inserted
END
```

What it basically does is it sets the LastUpdated column for all rows in inserted and the DisturbedSince column for a subset of the inserted rows.

Finally the inserted rows get copied to a history table. (Every change on any row must be saved for two days). Older data gets deleted by a maintenance job.

As we have up to ~ 300 rows updated per second (Updates to rows can be batched together) We create a big amount of data and recursive updates.

I've now found the INSTEAD OF UPDATE triggers which seem to solve the recursive UPDATE problem caused by my trigger but I would have to process every row of the inserted table one by one with an update statement in the trigger.

I'm not sure if this is really faster. Does anyone of you have a recommendation?

What I really need is to tweak / extend the data rows before they are send to the table. Is there an approach for this?

e.g.: Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE inserted SET LastUpdated = getdate()
    UPDATE inserted SET DisturbedSince 
     WHERE Vehicle_Number IN (SELECT Vehicle_Number FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Emergency_Stop = 1)
       AND Vehicle_Number IN (SELECT Vehicle_Number FROM deleted WHERE deleted.Emergency_Stop = 0)
    "SAVE INSERTED"
END
```

and an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER with the storage of the changed data to the history table.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Thomas

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: "I would have to process every row of the inserted table one by one with an update statement in the trigger." - um, why do you believe that?

Comment: @Marc: It's an MS-SQL Server 2014 database. I've added this to my question.

Comment: @Damien: As I understood the INSTEAD OF UPDATE triggers don't perform an UPDATE to the table. You must take care of it yourself in the trigger. Or am I mistaken? So I would need to go through the preview of the inserted table row by row and create a new UPDATE statement to really perform the update!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to think that using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger is the right way to go rather than an `AFTER` trigger, when you're wanting to change data within the same table as well.

It would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_T_TPM_Vehicle_Update] ON [dbo].[T_TPM_Vehicle]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE tgt
SET
   Vehicle_Ref = i.Vehicle_Ref,
   Vehicle_Type = i.Vehicle_Type,
   ...
   LastUpdated = getdate(),
   DisturbedSince = CASE WHEN i.Emergency_Stop=1 and d.Emergency_Stop=0
                    THEN getdate() ELSE d.DisturbedSince END
OUTPUT
   inserted.[Vehicle_Ref]
  ,inserted.[Vehicle_Number]
  ,inserted.[Vehicle_Type]
  ...
  ,inserted.[HUIdent2]
  ,inserted.[HUType]
  ,inserted.[DisturbedSince] 
INTO T_TPM_Vehicle_HistoricalData
       ([Vehicle_Ref]
       ,[Vehicle_Number]
       ,[Vehicle_Type]
       ...
       ,[HUIdent2]
       ,[HUType]
       ,[DisturbedSince])
FROM
   T_TPM_Vehcile tgt
      inner join
   inserted i
      on
         tgt.Vehicle_Number = i.Vehicle_Number
      inner join
   deleted d
      on
         tgt.Vehicle_Number = d.Vehicle_Number
```

You'll note that I've combined both the `UPDATE`s and the `INSERT` into the history table into a single compound statement.

You'll also note that it's slightly confusing because there are two `inserted`s in play here - the `inserted` as part of the trigger (aliased as `i` to sidestep some of the confusion) and the `inserted` as part of the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try

Comment: I assume that in the DisturbedSince "update" it should be CASE WHEN ... THEN .... ELSE d.DisturbedSince END ?

Comment: @ThomasVoß - yes, sorry. Not got your tables so I can't test the code.

Comment: I've implemented that trigger to two tables now (those with the highest change rate) and I traced the procedure causing the updates for a while. A batch of 52 procedure calls (that's a batch of 52 updated rows) took at a maximum 270 milliseconds instead of 412 with the old version. Surely only a short test but if this really is the improvement (35%) it worth shipping it to the customer to have a long term test.
Thank you.